# Extract data from responses and calculate mean using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to check the performance of API using Apache Jmeter 2.11. The response data for HTTP request is as follows:

```
{
"global_id": 11111,
"name": "IMG_001.JPG",
"width": "1111",
"height": "1111",
"time_taken": {
  "segment_1_time": 1,
  "segment_2_time": 1,
  "segment_3_time": 27,
  "segment_4_time": 1,
  "segment_5_time": 56,
  "segment_6_time": 8,
  "total_time": 94
 }
}
```

Thread Properties:
Number of threads: 1,
Ramp-up period(in seconds): 1,
Loop Count: 50

I want to calculate the aggregate mean time taken by each segment for all the responses i.e. Mean time taken by segment_1, Mean time taken by segment_2, Mean time taken by segment_3, Mean time taken by segment_4, Mean time taken by segment_5 and Mean time taken by segment_6.

What are the post processors and javascript required for calculating the mean segments' times?

Comment: Do you mean avg response time for each Loop?

Comment: No. of threads:1 and Loop Count:50. That means total 50 requests will be sent to server. I want to calculate Mean time taken by each segment across the 50 responses. 
For instance, first response has "Segment_1_time":1, second response has "Segment_1_time":3, third response has "segment_1_time": 5 and so on. The mean time for segment_1 will be (1+3+5)/3 = 3.

I want to calculate the response time for each segment(1,2,...,6) in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **regular expression extractor** with **beanshell post processor**,

First, you need to extract your segment value using **regular expression extractor** with proper **Regex** like **segment_1_time":(.*?),** etc.

Next,
use **beanshell post processor** to calculate the Total value of each segment time,

```
var CurrentSegmentValue=vars.get("SEGMENT1");//Current segment value from Regular expression extractor

log.info("CurrentSegmentValue = "+CurrentSegmentValue);

/* You need to use this logic to calculate other segment values like SEGMENT2,3,4,5,6 etc
 *  but remember this method makes performace bottle neck when you have tested with higher number of threads
 *  and result may be differ see any appropriate web links for Jmeter performance tuning and suggested to use 64 bit JVM
 */

var totalvalueString=vars.get("totalValue");

if(totalvalueString==null)
{
vars.put("totalValue","0");
}

int totalValue= java.lang.Integer.parseInt(CurrentSegmentValue)+java.lang.Integer.parseInt(totalvalueString);

vars.put("totalValue",""+totalValue);

log.info("Final Total Value:"+totalValue);

//Going to next loop
/*Divide total value with number of threads you will get your mean time*/
```

In above code each segment value from response is saved and added with previous value.

Finally you can divide it  with number of threads to get mean

Hopes this may help you and refer this link for more information about **[bean shell scripting](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)**

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Nithin. In the above code:
    `int totalValue= java.lang.Integer.parseInt(tt)+java.lang.Integer.parseInt(tt1);`

what do "tt" and "tt1" refer to?

Comment: I used **regular expression extractor** with the following fields:  Reference name: s1time, Regular expression: "segment_1_time": (\d+), Template: $1$, Match No: 1, Default Value: 0   and then I wrote this script in **bean shell postprocessor**  `var time_s1= vars.get("s1time");  String s1time= vars.get("s1time");  
log.info("Time taken by segment1 per response(from var) = "+time_s1);  log.info("Time taken by segment1 per response(from string) = "+s1time);`  but both of these return null.

Comment: I couldn't point out any issues right now, check below points which may help you to solve the issue 

**1.** Check regular expression with wildcard characters .* and log the value in console. 
**2.** Check & try to design Test plan as **Http Sampler** -----> **RegularExpressionExtractor** -----> **BeanshellPostProcessor** 
         
**3.** You can also use JSON Path Extractor(http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/‎) from Jmeter plugin addon(Free) to parse json response (http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Use debug sampler to see what your regex extractor is extracting and what variables are set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to try other test tool, you may want to look at [NetGend](http://www.netgend.com).  Here is a [blog](http://perftestingng.blogspot.com/2014/04/averaging-over-json-fields.html) that shows how this scenario is implemented on NetGend platform - so simple that you don't need a lot of programming background to understand it.

Good luck.